# Custom fill colour of bin with highest density in geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, fill, bins

My sample data frame goes as follows:

```
a <- structure(list(Middlepoint = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 7, 18, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8.5, 8.5)), .Names = "Middlepoint", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-34L))
```

I would like to create a histogram of `binwidth = 1` and of the characteristics as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(a, aes(x = Middlepoint)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., fill=..density..), binwidth = 1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:19) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "red", high = "green")
```

Now, what I cannot figure out is how to color just *the bin of highest density* (here, bin 8-9) with green color and all other bins with red (no gradient, just straight colors).

As you can see from the code above, the closest I could get to the desired outcome is to use `scale_fill_continuous()` component which is close but not exactly how I would like to see it.
I tried threads like [ggplot change fill colour without losing colour gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935195/ggplot-change-fill-colour-without-losing-colour-gradient) and [R - ggplot2 histogram conditional fill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323642/r-ggplot2-histogram-conditional-fill-color).
Any ideas how to generally custom fill histogram's bins?

Comment: There is no `percent` object in your example.

Comment: Add `library(scales)`

Comment: Thnx for answers & hints! The general idea behing is because the only acceptable occuring values should be withing the green bin (8€-9€). The others, red bins are not acceptable, hence, visual issue that results in my problem. @Henrik

Comment: @Henrik Bin with the highest density is the reasoning you are looking for. I did not consider ties with x values per se, I considered the color ties with the bin of highest density. Thanx for advice I will be more knowledgeable in the future Qs. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `fill` argument to a `factor` which takes 2 levels: one for all the density values lower then the `max` and one for the maximum density:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x = Middlepoint)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y    = ..density.., 
                     fill = cut(..density.., c(0, sort(..density.., TRUE)[1:2]))), 
                 binwidth = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual("", values = c("red", "green")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Histogram]

Comment: Thnx @thothal, that's what I wanted to do!